# How to Route to different components in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have been trying to use ReactJS route using react-router where I have a container that holds innner component. I keep getting "ReferenceError: path is not defined" even when I have handled my imports properly.

Route.js

```
const Main = props => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/' component={Login} />
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={Signup} />
    </Switch>
);

export default Main;
```

Container.js

```
class Container extends React.Component{
render() {
    return (
        <div className="onboarding">
            <div className="container middle">
                <div className="inner">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-4">
                            <img src="/assets/img/logo.svg"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <Main />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Container;
```

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <Container>
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>Welcome Back!<span></span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <form className="onboard-form">
                        <div className="input-ctn">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="input-ctn">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className=""/>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" 
    className="btn-block"/>

                    </form>

                    <p className="text-center">Don't have an 
    account? <BrowserRouter><Link to="/sign-up">Sign Up</Link> . 
    </BrowserRouter></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        </Container>
       );
    }
}

export default Login
```

Signup.js

```
class Signup extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <Container>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>Hello there!<span></span></h3>
                    <p>Signup</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <form className="onboard-form">
                        <div className="input-ctn">
                            <label>Please enter your phone 
number</label>
                            <input type="tel" 
placeholder="08123456789"/>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Get Started" 
className="btn-block"/>
                    </form>
                    <p className="text-center">Already have an 
account? <a href="#">Log In</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>

        </Container>
    );
    }
}

export default Signup
```

I am expected to load the login page as the landing page and navigate to /sign-up as the signup page where both of them have the same container. Here is the full error message I get

```
ReferenceError: path is not defined
at /Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/lib/server.js:13:18
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at param (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:354:14)
at param (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:365:14)
at Function.process_params (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:410:3)
at next (/Users/myUser/Documents/Website Projects/React Projects/myProject/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
```

Comment: Can you show the full error message?

Comment: You need to import and use the browserRouter Seethe basic example here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic

Comment: @ic3b3rg I have added the error message now

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple things that you need to correct as part of your code.

1. You container takes the children, but you haven't rendered any within it.
2. With your current pattern if you render children, if will become and infinite recursion, since container renders children, and children render container
3. BrowserRouter must be present as a wrapper at top level and not as a wrapper of just the `Link` component
4. Your Routes within `Main` component needs re-ordering, else they will always render the route with path `/`

**Container**

```
class Container extends React.Component{

    render() {
        return (
          <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="onboarding">
                <div className="container middle">
                    <div className="inner">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-4">
                                <img src="/assets/img/logo.svg"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Route component={Main} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
        );
      }
}

export default Container;
```

---

Router.js

```
const Main = props => (
    <Switch>
        <Route path='/sign-up' component={Signup} />
        <Route path='/' component={Login} />
    </Switch>
);

export default Main;
```

---

Signup.js

```
class Signup extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <h3>Hello there!<span></span></h3>
                        <p>Signup</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-12">
                        <form className="onboard-form">
                            <div className="input-ctn">
                                <label>Please enter your phone 
    number</label>
                                <input type="tel" 
    placeholder="08123456789"/>
                            </div>

                            <input type="submit" value="Get Started" 
    className="btn-block"/>
                        </form>
                        <p className="text-center">Already have an 
    account? <a href="#">Log In</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
               </React.Fragment>
            );
        }
}

export default Signup
```

---

Login.js

```
class Login extends React.Component{
render(){
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <h3>Welcome Back!<span></span></h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <form className="onboard-form">
                        <div className="input-ctn">
                            <label>Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email"/>
                        </div>

                        <div className="input-ctn">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" className=""/>
                        </div>

                        <input type="submit" value="Log In" 
    className="btn-block"/>

                    </form>

                    <p className="text-center">Don't have an 
    account? <Link to="/sign-up">Sign Up</Link>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
       );
    }
}

export default Login
```

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/14qmj37vzl)

Comment: With this, I still get the same error for sign-up. only the landing page works still

Comment: did you reorder the routes and remove the container component from signgup page too

Comment: The signup component needs to be wrapped within <React.Fragment>, Added a working demo too

Comment: Yes, I did reorder the routes. Also, I removed the container component from signup. I just added  <React.Fragment> as you suggested also. I still have the same result. Please note that: If I do http://localhost:9090/sign-up I get the error above, if I do http://localhost:9090/#/sign-up, it still shows the landing page.

Comment: Do I need ReactDom.render anywhere?

Comment: Please check the demo link. Its perfectly working ` localhost:9090/#/sign-up`is route with hash and won't work with BrowserRoutes

Comment: With ReactDOM.render, you would render your container into the HTML at the top level. Also make sure you are using react-router-dom v4 and do check the imports

Comment: Its actually driving me crazy now, all checked and intact and cant still figure it to work.
 "react-dom": "^16.6.3",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"
I have checked the working demo too and followed all steps. All imports are correctly done. React version is "react": "^16.6.3"

Comment: Are you using server side rendering??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185677/discussion-between-temi-topsy-bello-and-shubham-khatri).

Comment: all that and you did not receive a thumbs up? I gave you a thumbs up!!!